# Context Menu is not displayed on the right position when the list is bigger

Tags: css

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $("body").on("contextmenu", "table tbody button", function(e) {
    $(".contextMenu").hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.contextMenu').css({
      display: "block",
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
    return false;
  });
  $(".contextMenu").on("click", "a", function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $("html").click(function() {
    $(".contextMenu").hide();
  });
  $scope.nodes = [{
      "id": 228,
      "name": "Folder 1",
      "descr": "",
      "path": "227/",
      "mm": true
    },
    {
      "id": 229,
      "name": "Folder 2",
      "descr": "",
      "path": "227/",
      "mm": true
    }
  ];
  $scope.deleteFolder = function(detailid) {
    console.log(detailid);
    alert(detailid)
  };
});
```

```css
.contextmenustyle {
  display: block;
  position: static;
}

.contextMenu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="foldertable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center">
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="projtable">
    <tr ng-repeat="detail in nodes" ng-mouseover="showShare()">
      <td><button id="namesdetails" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="openFolder(detail.id, detail.name)" style="text-decoration: none !important">
                                    <span class="fa fa-folder" style="font-size: larger"></span> 
                                    {{detail.name}}</button>
        <div class="dropdown clearfix contextMenu">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu contextmenustyle" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" ng-click="editFolderName(detail.id, detail.name)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit/Rename</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" ng-click="deleteFolder(detail.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!--            pop up to confirm  delete-->
        <div id="delModel" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog  modal-sm">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you Sure you want to Delete?</p>
                <div align="right">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="okdelete()">Yes</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <!--            pop up to rename folder-->
        <div id="editFolder" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog  modal-sm">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editfoldername" ng-model="editfoldername">
                <br>
                <div align="right">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="updateName()">Update</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </td>



    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Could someone please suggest me on what should I change in the CSS of the context menu, so that I see the menu just right by even if the list is bigger. 
It works fine for me when the list is smaller. Attached the Image. 
[image]
The red line shows where I have clicked and where the menu is actually popped up.

```
.contextMenu {
  position: fixed;
  display:none;
}
.contextmenustyle
{
    display:block;position:static;margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: I think it would help me more to understand this if you provide css for your list item and its wrapper as well as whether you are using javascript or jquery to make contextMenu x, y position on mouse right click.

Comment: I use jquery for context menu. Updated my original post

Answer (score 0):

if you are share full code, i can help you

try this.

```
.contextMenu {
  position: relative;
  display:none;
}
.contextmenustyle
{
    display:block;position:absolute;margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the original post. The changes suggested by you doesnt help. May be after seeing the full code you can help me out more